# Java Socket : I'm trying to generate random port numbers between a range, but connection is refused, but when I'm using a integer, it works

Tags: java, sockets, random, port

Client :

```
public class FileClient {  

static int Min = 1050;
static int Max = 15000;
static int PORT = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", PORT);  
        if (PORT>=2000&&PORT<=2050) {
            System.out.println("The rare disconnection");
            sock.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Connection Opened");
        // sendfile  
        File myFile = new File("input.txt");  
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];  
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  
        System.out.println("Input Stream Opened");
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();  
        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  
        System.out.println("Data written to output file");
        os.flush();  
        bis.close();  
        System.out.println("Input Stream Closed");
        sock.close();  
        System.out.println("Connection Closed");
    }  
}
```

Server:

```
public class FileServer {      

   public static void main (String[] args ) throws IOException {     
      int XPORT = FileClient.PORT;
      int bytesRead;  
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(XPORT);
      System.out.println("Listening for a client");
      while(true) {  
         Socket clientSocket = null;  
         clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  
         InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();  
         // Writing the file to disk  
         // Instantiating a new output stream object  
         OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");  
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
         while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {  
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);  
         }  
         // Closing the FileOutputStream handle  
         output.close();  
      }
   }
}
```

Java Socket : I'm trying to generate random port numbers between a range, but connection is refused, but when I'm using a integer, it works. This is working for one value. I want the server to deny the connection for a few port numbers (Ex: 2000-2100)
And want the connection to be accepted and file transfer to be completed. When using integers, my file transfer works perfectly.

Comment: The server will only accept a connection on a specific port (Ex. All of them but one; you might bind to additional ports - but you haven't here). Which one port? That's part of the protocol. Your example might work for one machine, but with a network it seems specious at best.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the client you get one random number. When you run the server you get another. They're almost certainly different. There's no reason to expect this to work, and there's no reason to even try. Use a fixed port number. There are plenty available.

Comment: +1 but to confirm this assertion we need the script which is used to start the client and the server.

Comment: @Aubin No we don't. There's nothing in the answer to suggest that there even is a script. Both classes have `main()` methods, so they can be started in separate JVMs. If they are both started in separate JVMs, that would account for the problem entirely. If they were both started in the same JVM, the problem wouldn't occur. Ergo they weren't.

Comment: This would not result in two different numbers, one random number was generated in Client file and was taken in Server file. There was only one port generated. I have to use multiple ports since that was the whole idea to see if it works.

Comment: @EJP I am not using random function twice, I am just using the value from the client calculation. So, pardon me if I'm missing something, how would two different numbers be generated ?

Comment: The port will only be the same if you are running it from the same process. Which this code cannot do. I suggest you write some logging code that outputs the port number that you are listening/connecting to

Comment: You are indeed using the random function twice. You are starting two JVMs, so the field is initialized twice, once per JVM, and so you get two different random numbers. That's what you're supposed to get with random number generators. If you want to debate this point further you will need to trace the numbers you're getting and post them here as evidence of your claim.